# Router Remote Access

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, browser

On my TP-Link Archer CR700 router, I have gone to administrator settings, ticked the box that says enable remote access, saved settings, went to Router status page, copied the router public IP address, went to browser, typed in router public IP address:8080  — as recommended in the router instructions — but it still will not display anything.

I have tried including `https://` and I have tried disabling WAN Bblocking, but it does not help. What am I missing?

Comment: What WAN IP does your router report? (I'm wondering if the issue is CGN). Also, you really need to specify the model of router if we are to help you.

Comment: what is the router model?

Comment: TP-Link Archer CR700

Comment: You are trying to access the **global ip address** from your local lan... **This is called NAT hairpin/NAT loopback,** Cheap consumer routers usually don't have this feature in their firmware. Either test from something like canyouseeme.org, or go to a hotspot, work, or friends connection to test the port forwards. If the port forwards fail testing this way you most likely have **Carrier Grade NAT**. Google CGN.

Comment: **I have voted to close this question** as both CGN & NAT-Hairpin have been covered extensively on SU. The question needs more information to determine what the problem actually is, I would start with checking the port forwards externally.

Comment: If they've been covered extensively, then you probably want to vote duplicate to at least point Sandcastle in the right direction. There is enough detail here to give a reasonable answer to the question, given as how you just answered it.